# Why are there so many Java frameworks that have the same functionality?

Tags: java, frameworks, computer-science, standards

I've noticed there are a lot of frameworks that basically serves the same purpose, like ORMs, MVC frameworks, etc. Wouldn't it be better all those guys can get together and work on one framework for one problem domain rather than wasting effort on reinventing the wheel? Are there any process that undertakes the task, or is it unlikely that it will ever happen? Would it be a good thing or is diversity good as in "Competition breeds perfection"? Personally I think if someone can standardize a singular framework for a single problem it will make life a lot easier as well as improving the framework really fast. Am I misguided?

Comment: Why are there so many different makes of cars? So many brands of pencils?

Comment: Because people is free to do what ever they like, basically

Comment: One size doesn't fit all

Comment: Java already has a set of standard frameworks in Java EE. Nine women won't make a baby in one month – there's no reason for every framework author to drop what they're doing and rush to the Java EE reference implementation projects.

Comment: You sound like a Microsoft developer to me.  I think you are misguided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's all about the right tool for the task. There are a lot of programming languages too, but each has a slightly different approach. Check out this comparison of Java framework features to see what I mean: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Web_application_frameworks#Java_2

One framework may require that code be written in a certain way. Some programmers will embrace it, because it will result in more consistent code. Other frameworks let the programmer choose how they build their application. Again, some may like the flexibility that this offers.